# Google Translate php library Fail with Service Account in Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, google-translate

I'm using google php api to manage translate.

I follow the steps in google: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php

I think that works because i put this in my php command line:

```
$translate = new Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient(['projectId' => 'projectid-183521' ]);
            $result = $translate->translate('Hola mundo', [
                'target' => 'en',
                'source' => 'es',
                'format' => 'text'
 ]);
```

Result:

```
[
     "source" => "es",
     "input" => "Hola mundo",
     "text" => "Hello World",
     "model" => null,
   ]
```

But when I run in my php project (laravel):

```
 production.ERROR: Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": ".",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I'm using: php7.1, apache2.4, ubuntu 16.04 on AWS with load balancer.

Any idea how to solve this will be great! Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key on your ubuntu?

Comment: Yes,I did! I export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/ubuntu/mykeyfile.json" in my .bashrc file

Answer (score 4):

As [@JL-HN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4271067/jl-hn) said the problem was about environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, for security reason apache don't read ubuntu environment variables, so I declare the environment variable in Apache *.conf file:

```
SetEnv GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS /home/mycredentials.json
```

And works!